# What is heap table (as DB storage format)?

Tags: sql-server

What is **heap table** (as DB storage format)?

According to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_%28data_structure%29 heap is special data structure with properties that I can't directly map to DB performance benefits...

I found a lot of *heap vs clustered* discussions and understand that is clustered (there are a lot of images and definitions) but *heap* tables are not defined at all...

Comment: A heap is a table without a clustered index. [Reference](http://www.sqlbadpractices.com/heap-tables/)

Comment: @user1429080 So *heap table* have no conjunction with *heap data structure*?

Comment: @user1429080: the terms "heap table" and "clustered index" (especially together) are SQL Server specific, not a general "database term"

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name So it a vendor (MS) marketing term for non-clustered tables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quoting from [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/hh213609.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) MSDN link:

> A heap is a table without a clustered index.

One or more nonclustered indexes can be created on tables stored as a heap. Data is stored in the heap without specifying an order. Usually data is initially stored in the order in which is the rows are inserted into the table, but the Database Engine can move data around in the heap to store the rows efficiently; so the data order cannot be predicted

> The most crucial part is that the data storage order on disk becomes non
>   deterministic in heap tables as you have NOT defined any clustered
>   index on it.

Once you define a clustered index on a table having a column let's say Id (of type int) you can say with guarantee that a row with id 1 will come before the row with id 2 in database page files. More useful information related to heap tables in SQL Server can be found [here](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/database-administration/sql-server-heaps-and-their-fragmentation/) and [here](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1254/clustered-tables-vs-heap-tables/).

Answer (score 1):

In short, a heap is a table in SQL Server without a clustered index. But..

Table scans on heaps follow the allocation order, as written in IAM pages; clustered tables follow the doubly-linked ordered list of pages (mostly to avoid some consistency problems, so if an X lock on the table or the READ UNCOMMITTED is in effect you can get the allocation order scan with clusters as well).

Heaps can be faster in an NCI seek + lookup scenario than clustered tables. The leaf level of NCIs on heaps contains the physical pointer to data, as opposed to clusters where there is a value of clustered index instead, which in most cases requires several more reads from non-leaf levels on CI to navigate the b-tree structure and find the data.

If there are variable-length columns in a heap, an update increasing the length of the columns could cause the whole row to move to some other page, leaving a forwarding pointer in place (that's to avoid updating all the NCIs with new pointers to the data). This could be very bad for the performance and the only cure is to rebuild the table.

As a rule of thumb, in SQL Server use clustered tables, unless you have a very good reason not to.